# Modify keys of a list of object

Tags: javascript

I have a list of objects :

```
userEvents : [
    {title : "now", start : "after", end : "when it ends"},
    {title : "now", start : "after", end : "when it ends"},
    {title : "now", start : "after", end : "when it ends"}
]
```

And I want to change the keys of the object like : `title` I want it to be `eventName`, Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like so:

```
for( var i = 0; i < userEvents.length; i++ ) {

    userEvents[i].eventName = userEvents[i].title;
    delete userEvents[i].title;
}
```

This works by defining a new property `eventName` on each object in the `userEvents` list, then copies the reference to the string, then deleting the old `title` property. The underlying string object which the `title` and `eventNames` properties refer to is unchanged and retained.

(`delete` in JavaScript will cause a variable or property to become `undefined`, whereas in C++ it invokes the `~T` destructor)

Comment: I thought there will be a built in function but this will do. Thanks

Comment: @MoatezBouhdid You can rename properties in a single go, but only if they share the same `prototype`. When objects are defined using Javascript's object-literal notation (as in your example) then there is no prototype-inheritance so there is no object-constructor or prototype to modify.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please don't downvote without at least providing constructive feedback in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var someobject = {userEvents : [{
    title: "now",
    start: "after",
    end: "when it ends"
}, {
    title: "now",
    start: "after",
    end: "when it ends"
}, {
    title: "now",
    start: "after",
    end: "when it ends"
}]}


for( var i = 0; i < someobject.userEvents.length; i++ ) {
    var obj = someobject.userEvents[i];
    for(var j in obj){
        if(j === "title"){
            obj["eventName"] = obj[j];
            delete obj[j];
        }
    }
}

console.log(someobject.userEvents);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're after a self-contained generic function to do this, it's simple enough to mock something up (credit to other answers here already):

```
function rename_keys (obj_arr, key_map) {
  return obj_arr.map(
    (obj) => {
      for (var key in key_map) {
        obj[ key_map[ key ] ] = obj[ key ];
        delete obj[ key ];
      }
      return obj;
    }
  );
}
```

The first parameter is an array of objects to modify. The second parameter is an object that defines which keys to rename and to what. Sample usage:

```
rename_keys(
  [
    {a:3,b:5}, {a:4,b:6}
  ],
  {
    b:'c'
  }
);
// results in:
// [
//   {a:3,c:5}, {a:4,c:6}
// ]
```

Note: this will modify the original objects and return a new array of the same objects. Extra steps have to be taken if you don't want that to happen.

Note 2: while generally it's not advised to modify the core objects, if you *wanted to* you *could* make this a member function of any array:

```
Array.prototype.rename_keys = function (key_map) {
  return rename_keys( this, key_map );
};
// then, this is possible:
userEvents.rename_keys( {title: 'eventName'} );
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `Array.prototype.map` instead of the other poster's naive implementation. It's best to use more modern functional style these days.

```
userEvents.map(function(obj) {
    obj.eventName = obj.title;
});
```

Comment: I'm curious why you refer to my solution as "naive" :) or what authority on JavaScript says the functional style "is best".

Comment: You are allocating an useless array. Do not misuse `map`.